# Model from Caterpillar to Butterfly in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, model

I was recently asked this question in an interview:

> Model animals that change their behaviour over time.
>
> 1. Can you model a butterfly?
>
>    - A butterfly can fly  * A butterfly does not make a sound
> 2. Can you optimize your model to account for the metamorphosis from caterpillar to butterfly?
>
>    - A caterpillar cannot fly
>    - A caterpillar can walk (crawl)

I created a hierarchy with a top level interface (`Insect`) which had 2 interfaces extending it (`GroundInsect` & `FlyingInsect`). Then I had `Caterpillar` implementing `GroundInsect` and `ButterFly` implementing `FlyingInsect`. However, I wasn't able to come up with a solution for the metamorphosis part. Below is my code:

**Insect Interface:**

```
public interface Insect { }
```

**FlyingInsect Interface:**

```
public interface FlyingInsect extends Insect {
    public boolean fly();
}
```

**GroundInsect interface:**

```
public interface GroundInsect extends Insect {
    // Walk/Crawl
    public boolean walk();
}
```

**Caterpillar class:**

```
public class Caterpillar implements GroundInsect {

    @Override
    public boolean walk()
    {
        System.out.println("Caterpillar Walk method");
        return true;
    }
}
```

**ButterFly class:**

```
public class Butterfly implements FlyingInsect {

    @Override
    public boolean fly() {
        System.out.println("ButterFly Flying method");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Would you consider the current lifecyle of an insect to be a `state`? I might have tried to use a State Design Pattern. I'm curious as to what others think.

Comment: You "make" a butterfly from a caterpillar, so one way to model it is to construct a butterfly from a c caterpillar : `new Butterfly(Caterpillar  caterpillar)`. Alternatively have a `Butterfly` implement  `FlyingInsect` and  `GroundInsect` and change it behavior with age.

Comment: @c0der I don't think you *make* from one, you make from *self*, I see this rather different

Comment: @Sameervb, have one of the answers given satisfied you? If not, what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Let's keep the example simple and stick to your initial approach.

First, I would introduce a general interface describing all kinds of insects:

```
interface Insect {
    boolean fly();
    boolean walk();
    boolean sound();
}
```

The methods `fly`, `walk`, `sound` represent possible interactions between an insect and its neighbourhood (depending on the nature of these interactions the methods might be different and more involved: returning complex responses, accepting callbacks, etc.).

Your first butterfly would be just some concrete implementation of the interface:

```
class Butterfly implements Insect {
    boolean fly() { return true; }
    boolean walk() { return true; }
    boolean sound() { return false; }
}
```

Now let's add the ability to transform. Again, in general there are various ways to do it, so let's stick to the butterfly example.

Let's say we want a caterpillar and it's related butterfly to be a single entity (we don't want the caterpillar to still wander around when the butterfly is already there).

In this case I would represent both caterpillar and butterfly as a single class and hide it's current state inside it. Both "caterpillar state" and "butterfly state" will contain different implementations of actions that should change after transformation. The enclosing instance will delegate it's methods to current state.

```
class Butterfly implements Insect {

    private Insect state = new CaterpillarState();

    boolean fly() { return state.fly(); }
    boolean walk() { return state.walk(); }
    boolean sound() { return state.sound(); }

    void transform() { state = new ButterflyState(); }

    private class ButterflyState implements Insect {
        boolean fly() { return true; }
        boolean walk() { return true; }
        boolean sound() { return false; } 
    }

    private class CaterpillarState implements Insect {
        boolean fly() { return false; }
        boolean walk() { return true; }
        boolean sound() { return true; }             
    }
}
```

The `transform` method represents a trigger for the metamorphosis.

Here `ButterflyState` and `CaterpillarState` implement the same `Insect` interface as the outer class. In general case I would probably define a different interface for internal states.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add a third contract that combines the two interfaces. This is because I believe whether it's a butterfly or a caterpillar, it should be the same `Insect` instance.

The following is a specialized contract that adds `UnsupportedOperationException` as an option:

```
interface FlyingGroundInsect extends FlyingInsect, GroundInsect {

    boolean ableToFly();

    boolean ableToWalk();

    /**
     * As per {@link GroundInsect#walk walk}. This may throw
     * UnsupportedOperationException if the animal's stage doesn't allow flying
     * 
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException If animal is unable to walk
     */
    @Override
    boolean walk();

    /**
     * As per {@link FlyingInsect#fly fly}. This may throw
     * UnsupportedOperationException if the animal's stage doesn't allow walking
     * 
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException If animal is unable to fly
     */
    @Override
    boolean fly();
}
```

And this single class is for the butterfly insect, which is understood to represent the insect that starts as a caterpillar and later changes into a butterfly (as per the `age` state - it can be more precise or sophisticated).

```
class Butterfly implements FlyingGroundInsect {

    private int age;

    @Override
    public boolean fly() {
        if (!this.ableToFly())
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Too early to fly");

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean walk() {
        System.out.println("Walk method");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean ableToFly() {
        return this.age >= 28;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean ableToWalk() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really interesting question. I liked your idea of creating the interfaces `GroundInsect` and `FlyingInsect`, but I would have declared `Insect` as an abstract class, as well as `Butterfly`, whose children classes would be the development stages of a butterfly (including a caterpillar and an adult butterfly). Anyway, instead of writing all the relations, which would be confusing, I've made a diagram. Look below:

[image: Diagram]

As for the metamorphosis part, I declared a new interface called `Metamorphosable` (pardon me the weird name, but I couldn't come up with anything better!) which contains a method to handle the metamorphosis of an insect. Moreover, the constructors of `Chrysalis` and `AdultButterfly` receives, as an argument, an instance of the preceding development stage. See my code below:

***Insect* class:**

```
public abstract class Insect {
    //...
    //sample method:
    public abstract void eat(); //all insects eats, but each specie (and each of its stages) has its own eating behaviour
}
```

***Butterfly* class:**

```
public abstract class Butterfly extends Insect {}
```

***Metamorphosable* interface:**

```
public interface Metamorphosable<T extends Insect> {
    public T metamorphosis();
}
```

***Caterpillar* class:**

```
public class Caterpillar extends Butterfly implements GroundInsect, Metamorphosable<Chrysalis>
{
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        //eating behaviour for the caterpillar
    }

    @Override
    public boolean walk() {
        System.out.println("Caterpillar walk() method!");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Chrysalis metamorphosis() {
        return new Chrysalis(this);
    }
}
```

***Chrysalis* class:**

```
public class Chrysalis extends Butterfly implements Metamorphosable<AdultButterfly>
{
    //Constructor
    public Chrysalis(Caterpillar caterpillar) {
        //init a new chrysalis from a caterpillar
    }

    @Override
    public void eat() {
        //eating behaviour for the chrysalis (it eats itself!)
    }

    @Override
    public AdultButterfly metamorphosis() {
        return new AdultButterfly(this);
    }
}
```

***AdultButterfly* class:**

```
public class AdultButterfly extends Butterfly implements FlyingInsect
{
    //Constructor
    public AdultButterfly(Chrysalis chrysalis) {
        //init a new butterfly from a chrysalis
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fly() {
        System.out.println("AdultButterfly fly() method!");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void eat() {
        //eating behaviour for the adult butterfly
    }
}
```